# Notification Hub Apple APNS Certificate Upload Failure

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I followed step by step this guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started/

I created all the certificates and all the stuff. Then I went to the newly created Notification Hub I got this response:

[image]

What does it means? Do I'm doing everything right? Anybody experiencing the same problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what the problem was. WAS NOT RELATED TO APPLE APN but to Google. The Google Key was wrong but and this does not allow me to upload the Apple cert!